# nextjs api routes not excepting body more than 1MB

Tags: next.js

I am trying to build a react image uploader application with nextjs api routes.
API is throwing error whenever the request body size is more than 1MB

tried the following config, still not working

```
export const config = { api: { bodyParser: { sizeLimit: "25mb", }, }, }
```

here is the link to reproduce https://codesandbox.io/s/next-with-api-forked-6mjlkd?file=/pages/api/test.js